# how can i setup an condition for value of object

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

suppose i have an object like this:

```
user = {
  Fullname: "name",
  password: "anonymous",
  confirm: "anonymous"
}
```

so i want to check value of this object is empty or not and password have to be at least 6 character and maximum 30 character. Thank you for advanced

and here my code but it didn't work. plz show me where am i wrong?

```
 var user = {
        username,
        password,
        confirm,
    };

    function check(a) {

            if (user.username != "") {
                return true
            }
            if (6 < user.password < 30) {
                return true
            }
            if (user.password = user.confirm) {
                return true
            } else {
                document.write("wrong");
                return false
            }

        console.log(user = {
            username = "adc",
            password = "sadcddddddcdcdcdcdcdcdcđcdcdcdcdcdc",
            confirm = "sadcddddddcdcdcdcdcdcdcđcdcdcdcdcdc",
        };);
    }
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work, but haven't said what it does instead. This doesn't do what you think it does though: `6 < user.password < 32`. Bases on the text you wrote, you want `6 <= user.password && user.password <= 30`. I'm dumbfounded as to where the `32` came from.

Comment: You also don't want to `return true;` as soon as a test passes. You don't want to return until all tests have passed or one has failed.

Comment: You're also looping for no reason and checking `a.length` when a is an object without a length property, which means your loop is never entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough at some point (e.g. please clarify: 'object is empty or not'), but so far I have modified the code as follows:

```js
var user = {
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  confirm: 'password',
};

var user_failed = {
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  confirm: 'password1',
};

var user_missing_password = {
  username: 'user',
}

var user_password_no_match = {
  username: 'user',
  password: ''
}

// returns false if failed the check
function check(user) {
  // for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  // what is this for loop for?
  if (!user.username) { // checks empty string, null or undefined
    document.write('NO USERNAME')
    return false // changes
  }
  if (user.password && typeof user.password === 'string' && user.password.length >= 6 && user.password.length <= 30) { // This is NOT Python! e.g. 6 < 7 < 3 will give you 'true'!
    if (user.password === user.confirm) {
      return true // same password, likely what you want
    } else {
      // I don't understand Vietnamese, sorry for possibly mistaking anything here
      // I would assume you till user that there is something wrong with this document.write
      document.write('PASSWORD DOES NOT MATCH')
      return false
    }
  }
  document.write('NO PASSWORD or BAD PASSWORD or PASSWORD TOO SHORT')
  return false;
  // }
}
    
console.log(check(user))
console.log(check(user_failed))
console.log(check(user_missing_password))
console.log(check(user_password_no_match))
```

Comment: Thank you for modify for me. Im a  newbie in js so sorry for my stupid mistake and VietNamese text if it bored you

Answer (score 0):

The `user` object structure is wrong. Also in the `if` conditional statement , you can all the conditions & if all met then return true else false

```js
var user = {
  username: "adc",
  password: "sadcddddddcdcdcdcdcdcdcđcdcdcdcdcdc",
  confirm: "sadcddddddcdcdcdcdcdcdcđcdcdcdcdcdc"
};

function check(a) {
  if ("" !== a.userName && 6 <= a.password && 30 >= a.password && a.password === a.confirm) {
    return !0;
  }
  document.write("bạn đã nhập sai");
  return !1;
}
check(user);
```